# Check performance of Installed app in WIndows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to check the performance (CPU, Memory, Battery, etc) of popular apps (like Facebook, Youtube, etc) on a Windows Phone Device. However, unlike iOS and Android, I do not see an option to check the performance of installed apps in Visual Studio. Is there a way to perform this analysis using any tools or is it only possible to check the performance of apps with source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for windows phone application analysis. From Visual Studio you can accessed for BUILD menu or ALT+F11

Comment: Using that analysis, I was only able to test for apps for which I have the source code. I need to test apps like Facebook or Youtube,

Comment: @Muhammad you may try to do it with windows phone developer power tools